# How to Read a File (DOCX or XLSX OR PNG) as Binary stream in Internet Explorer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, activexobject

For one of our customer, we are required to use HTML File Input control, to upload the file to another server using REST Web Services. I was able to achieve this using HTML FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer Method. But since users are using IE8 and IE9, HTML5 APIs are not supported. I tried using below code, but this reads only TXT file not other file types like DOCX or PNG

```
reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
```

Comment: I wonder if the best answer might be to use HTML5 FileAPI anyway, and use [a polyfill script](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api) for it in old IEs.

Answer (score 0):

I use file inputs in a weird working way in IE8, maybe it can help you:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = 'POST';
form.action = url;
form.target = '_blank';
form.encoding = form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
form.appendChild(fileInput);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

It sends the file chosen via fileInput as a POST request to the server, without reading its binary content. Do you absolutely need to read the file client-side ?

If you need cross-site upload, I think there are some iframe hacks for IE working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your quick response. The Web service which I am using is RESTfull service and accept the file as Base64string. So I need to read the file content at client side itself, convert it as Base64 String and pass it to the WebService. So I cannot use Post in there.

This is fully-being a client-side dependent script and at same time there is no handle at server side component I tried options of using ActiveX, but due to some security reason, we cannot proceed with that. I also tried ADO.Stream  but even that uses ActiveX.

Thanks,
Aravind